# Azure Pipelines: Why do my variables not set using the "key: value" syntax but do set with the "name, value" syntax?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I tried to change the syntax for defining my variables, but the variables are no longer being set. I thought I only needed to use the "name, value" syntax if I'm also using variable groups or templates and I'm not, so I wanted to use "key: value" syntax instead because it's more readable.

However, when I switched to the more readable syntax, the `Private.RevisionVersion`, `pythonPackageVersion`, and `nugetPackageVersion` variables are not being set (as seen in the output of the first code snippet).

"key: value" syntax (Not working):

```yaml
variables:
  Private.MajorMinorVersion: 1.2
  
  isFinalRelease: false
  isReleaseCandidate: false
  isAlpha: true

  ${{ if eq(variables['isFinalRelease'], 'true') }}:
    Private.RevisionVersion: $[counter(variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], 0)]
    pythonPackageVersion: $[format('{0}.{1}', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]
    nugetPackageVersion: $[format('{0}.{1}', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]
  ${{ if eq(variables['isReleaseCandidate'], 'true') }}:
    Private.RevisionVersion: $[counter(format('{0}rc', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion']), 1)]
    pythonPackageVersion: $[format('{0}rc{1}', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]
    nugetPackageVersion: $[format('{0}.{1}-rc', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]
  ${{ if eq(variables['isAlpha'], 'true') }}:
    Private.RevisionVersion: $[counter(format('{0}a', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion']), 1)]
    pythonPackageVersion: $[format('{0}a{1}', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]
    nugetPackageVersion: $[format('{0}.{1}-a', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]

jobs:
  - job: Echo_Variables
    steps:
      - script: echo $(Private.MajorMinorVersion) $(isFinalRelease) $(isReleaseCandidate) $(isAlpha)
      - script: echo $(Private.RevisionVersion) $(pythonPackageVersion) $(nugetPackageVersion)
```

Outputs:

```sh
echo 1.2 False False True
echo $(Private.RevisionVersion) $(pythonPackageVersion) $(nugetPackageVersion)
```

The `Private.RevisionVersion`, `pythonPackageVersion`, and `nugetPackageVersion` variables are not being set.

---

"name, value" syntax (Working):

```yaml
variables:
  - name: Private.MajorMinorVersion
    value: 1.2

  - name: isFinalRelease
    value: false

  - name: isReleaseCandidate
    value: false

  - name: isAlpha
    value: true

  - name: Private.RevisionVersion
    ${{ if eq(variables['isFinalRelease'], 'true') }}:
        value: $[counter(variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], 0)]
    ${{ if eq(variables['isReleaseCandidate'], 'true') }}:
        value: $[counter(format('{0}rc', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion']), 1)]
    ${{ if eq(variables['isAlpha'], 'true') }}:
        value: $[counter(format('{0}a', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion']), 1)]
    
  - name: pythonPackageVersion
    ${{ if eq(variables['isFinalRelease'], 'true') }}:
        value: $[format('{0}.{1}', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]
    ${{ if eq(variables['isReleaseCandidate'], 'true') }}:
        value: $[format('{0}rc{1}', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]
    ${{ if eq(variables['isAlpha'], 'true') }}:
        value: $[format('{0}a{1}', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]
        
  - name: nugetPackageVersion
    ${{ if eq(variables['isFinalRelease'], 'true') }}:
        value: $[format('{0}.{1}', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]
    ${{ if eq(variables['isReleaseCandidate'], 'true') }}:
        value: $[format('{0}.{1}-rc', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]
    ${{ if eq(variables['isAlpha'], 'true') }}:
        value: $[format('{0}.{1}-a', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]

jobs:
  - job: Echo_Variables
    steps:
      - script: echo $(Private.MajorMinorVersion) $(isFinalRelease) $(isReleaseCandidate) $(isAlpha)
      - script: echo $(Private.RevisionVersion) $(pythonPackageVersion) $(nugetPackageVersion)
```

Outputs:

```sh
echo 1.2 False False True
echo 1 1.2a1 1.2.1-a
```

As far I can tell, these are semantically identical. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If we switch the condition as below:

```
variables:
  Private.MajorMinorVersion: 1.2
  
  isFinalRelease: false 
  isReleaseCandidate: false 
  isAlpha: true

  ${{ if eq(variables['isFinalRelease'], 'true') }}:
    Private.RevisionVersion: $[counter(variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], 0)]
    pythonPackageVersion: $[format('{0}.{1}', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]
    nugetPackageVersion: $[format('{0}.{1}', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]
  ${{ if eq(variables['isAlpha'], 'true') }}:
    Private.RevisionVersion: $[counter(format('{0}a', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion']), 1)]
    pythonPackageVersion: $[format('{0}a{1}', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]
    nugetPackageVersion: $[format('{0}.{1}-a', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]
  ${{ if eq(variables['isReleaseCandidate'], 'true') }}:
    Private.RevisionVersion: $[counter(format('{0}rc', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion']), 1)]
    pythonPackageVersion: $[format('{0}rc{1}', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]
    nugetPackageVersion: $[format('{0}.{1}-rc', variables['Private.MajorMinorVersion'], variables['Private.RevisionVersion'])]

jobs:
  - job: Echo_Variables
    steps:
      - script: echo $(Private.MajorMinorVersion) $(isFinalRelease) $(isReleaseCandidate) $(isAlpha)
      - script: echo $(Private.RevisionVersion) $(pythonPackageVersion) $(nugetPackageVersion)
```

Outputs:

```
echo 1.2 False False True
echo 1 1.2a1 1.2.1-a
```

According to test result, it seems that it will not run the latest condition, It will only run the first two conditions.

I have report this issue to Developer Community, you could follow this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/define-variable-in-the-yaml/1406577?from=email) to get the latest news and if there are any updates, I will update here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is failing because `isAlpha` has the boolean value of `True`, and you're comparing it to the string `'true'`. Try using this expression for `isAlpha`:

```yaml
    ${{ if variables['isAlpha'] }}:
        value: ...
```

or

```yaml
    ${{ if eq(variables['isAlpha'], true) }}:
        value: ...
```

Comment: AFAIK, variables are always strings (only parameters have types). The first option invalidated the template with the errors `'Private.RevisionVersion' is already defined`, etc. The second option still does not set the variables (probably because `true` and `'true'` are the same for variables).